# Understanding Certificate Management in Application Publish, .NET Windows Application Clickonce

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, clickonce, publishing

I want to know the correct way of managing of publishing my windows application with .net clickonce.
every year I have to create a new test certificate so I can build my c# .net project and publish it. end users also have some problems with this certificate changes. does it need to have a certificate? can I remove it or change the validation period to more than one year?
please correct me if I am wrong in my question.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .net 3.5 signing a Clickonce application is optional.  Just uncheck the options to sign your manifest files.  If you do require a certificate and are creating your own, you can modify the expiration date on the certificate.  Set it to expire some point in the distant future and you don't have to worry about it expiring.

Here is a link from a blog that will explain how to create a certificate that does not expire.
[How to create non-expiring certificate](http://bernhardelbl.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/create-a-non-expiring-test-certificate-pfx-for-clickonce-applications/)